# FB like button show count bubble even when count is 0

Tags: facebook, count, facebook-like, zero

I am using the FB like button in "button" layout (count bubble immediately to the right of the like button, similar to twitter). The count bubble does not show up when there are zero likes, and I have heard in other places that it won't show up until there are at least 3 likes. I am wondering if there is a way to change this so that the count bubble shows up all the time no matter how many likes there are. Since all of the other social buttons do this, I have no idea why this exception should exist. It makes my social button bar look inconsistent. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to change that part of the behaviour of the like button with it's current settings.  You should submit your request to Facebook to have it looked at as a possible enhancement.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there is a way to do it, but it's not very nice. 
Instead of using the code suggested by facebook you can just include the raw iframe like this:

```
<iframe scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" 
style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:130px; height:25px; float:left; margin-right:10px;" 
src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=YOUR_URL_GOES_HERE&amp;layout=button_count&amp;show_faces=false&amp;width=130&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;height=21"></iframe>
```

What I also discovered is that if you add the part **&amp;sdk=joey** to the src attribute (which is what facebook's default code does) then the zero counter disappears. So it seems they just decided to cut this feature when they moved to new SDK.